# Xamarin.Forms : Need to go back to previous page on back button press even if entry has focus

Tags: xamarin.forms

If my entry field has focus and i click on hardware back button, the entry field looses focus but i am not able to navigate to previous page. I have to hit the back button again. I know this is the expected behaviour, but i need to navigate to the previous page on the first back button press itself. Need some help regarding this.

Comment: have you tried using OnBackButtonPressed?

Comment: That is not getting triggered on the first back button press. The entry is only loosing its focus.

Comment: Is there any other way of detecting the first back button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is by design.But you could use custom renderer and custom a EditText to achieve the effect.

1.create a **CustomEntry** :

```
public partial class CustomEntry:Entry
{

  public static readonly BindableProperty BackPressProperty=BindableProperty.Create("BackPress", typeof(EventHandler), typeof(CustomEntry), null);
  public event EventHandler BackPress;
  public void OnBack()
  {
    EventHandler eventHandler = this.BackPress;
    eventHandler?.Invoke((object)this, EventArgs.Empty);               
  }

}
```

2.create a custom EditText **MyEditText** in your Android project:

```
class MyEditText: FormsEditText
{
    public MyEditText(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public override bool OnKeyPreIme([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.onKeyBack();

                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.OnKeyPreIme(keyCode, e);
    }
    private OnEditTextKeyBackListener listener;

    public void setOnEditTextKeyBackListener(OnEditTextKeyBackListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public interface OnEditTextKeyBackListener
    {
        void onKeyBack();
    }

}
```

3.custom EntryRenderer **MyEntryRenderer**:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace EntryCa.Droid
{
class MyEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer,OnEditTextKeyBackListener
  {
    private Context context;
    private EditText editText;

    public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        MyEditText editText = new MyEditText(context);
        editText.setOnEditTextKeyBackListener(this);    
        editText.SetSingleLine(true);       //this and below line to set done key
        editText.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Done;    
        SetNativeControl(editText);     
    }


    public void onKeyBack()
    {
        hideSoftInput();
        ((CustomEntry)Element).OnBack();

    }
    InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
    public void hideSoftInput()
    {
        if (mInputMethodManager != null)
        {

            mInputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

4.use in your page.xaml:

```
<local:CustomEntry HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  WidthRequest="200" BackPress="CustomEntry_BackPress"></local:CustomEntry>
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
private void CustomEntry_BackPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Just one more question, it seems like after implementing this the completed event of the entry does not get triggered. Any particular reason?

Comment: @Debs As use the custom EditText, the default key in the bottom right corner of the keyboard is the enter key. You only need to set it as the done key in the custom renderer to respond to completed event.You could check the update above,in CustomRenderer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Actually i already had a custom renderer and upon hitting the enter key, the completed event was getting triggered, but after adding the above custom renderer code to that, its no longer triggering.. But I will look into that. Thank you once again.